# Rollercoaster Tycoon screen tearing

Tags: rollercoaster-tycoon

I've just decided to re-install RCT onto my system for a little fun.. All works fine and dandy (I bought it off of GoG.com, so it was downloaded up-to-date), the only issue I'm having is that the game tears TERRIBLY when I move the scene. I don't remember if this happened on my old computer (which probably wasn't running it at mind blowing FPS) but I did try limiting the FPS with afterburner. But yeah, it's that old that afterburner couldn't hook up to it.

I also tried DXtory, but that program loves to crash.  I tried forcing vsync in Nvidia control panel, but that didn't help at all.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: have you tried playing windowed mode?

Comment: @JLaBella RCT doesn't support windowed mode, unless you plan on playing the game through a virtual machine.

Comment: I play it on windowed mode... You just have to add -w to the shortcut properties(in the target directory) and its golden, because I was having tearing issues as well. Windowed fixed me up

Comment: @JLaBella That sounds like more of an answer than a comment. :)

Comment: What's your current OS and configuration ?

Comment: It is an answer, but I won't put it as one if the solution was already tried... (see first comment)

Comment: @JLaBella Fair enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these:

#### Compatibility modes

Setting the game to run in compatibility mode can help fix many issues with launching and playing the game. To do this, right-click the .exe, open Properties and set the game to run in Windows XP SP2 or Windows XP SP3 compatibility mode from the Compatibility tab.

#### Desktop composition

Some problems can be caused in Windows 7 and Windows Vista by having desktop composition enabled. To turn this off, check the 'Disable desktop composition' option from the Compatibility menu (right-click .exe > Properties > Compatibility).

<sup>Source: [PC Gaming Wiki, "RollerCoaster Tycoon" article](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/RollerCoaster_Tycoon)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

There are [official and unofficial patches for Roller Coaster Tycoon](http://www.rctstationarchive.com/downloads/patches.shtml) that could make it work better. The current official patch version is `1.08.187` – if your version isn't up to date, installing the most recent patch is the first thing to try.

If that doesn't help, you can try to:

- Launch in Windows 95 Compatibility Mode
- Disable Visual Themes in properties
- Disable Desktop Composition
- Run as Administrator (some restrictions make games unable to access some files)
- Try a virtual machine (VirtualBox should do it)

They are also kinda unstable in a 64 bits environment.

Comment: The version that is sold by GOG is RCT Deluxe which includes CF and LL, so the patch branch OP is looking for is 1.20, not 1.08.